# What's the difference between browser 'preferences' and 'desired capabilities'?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, download, capability

What's the difference between setting 'preferences' and 'desired capabilities' in the browser using Selenium?

I see people/blogs mentioning "`browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk`" as preference. But how do you distinguish between them?

Comment: I hope you find a better explanation from the previous question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777631/firefox-profile-preferences-vs-chrome-options-vs-ie-desired-capabilities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `desired capabilities` you are configuring the session as to what features should the session use. [Here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) is the link to show what all features a session can have by using desired capabilities.

Browser preferences are the features that a  browser use. For ex you may want to run your test with Firefox having certain startup page, language or want to do something with ssl certificate. [Here](https://seleniumbycharan.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/how-to-use-firefox-profile-preferences-in-selenium-webdriver/) and [here](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/firefox-profile-preferences-using-selenium-webdriver) are  links to show how to change browser prefrences using a profile.